# Hide all graphs with one click of a button in graph legend in amcharts

Tags: amcharts

I have a lot of graphs in one `Stockpanel` in `Amcharts`, so when I only want to show one of them, I have to close all legends one by one

Is there any way to create a button such than can hide all graphs in the legends?

I have seen some similar questions, but it is the example for `d3`, then how to solve in `Amcharts`?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily hide your graphs like this:

```
var panel = chart.panels[0]; // select the right panel here
for (var i = 0; i < panel.graphs.length; i++) {
    panel.hideGraph(panel.graphs[i]);
}
```

This will hide every single graph in this panel. You can exlude one by adding an if clause in the loop.

Comment: "I mean the button to hide all graphs" - that's exactly what my answer does.
"not hide permanently" - there's no such thing as temporary hidden. You have to unhide them manually (or with a timeout)

Comment: Please make a fiddle of it. I will take a look at it then.

Comment: @ gerric sorry, it really works, but this way may be not what I want, I want to create a button to close all graphs, as this way, it is not easy to open all the graphs.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand, what your demand is. With my answer you have a solution, that allows you to hide all graphs with a button. If you need an additional button, just copy it and use `showGraph()` instead. Else you have to get more clear what you need.